# How to use an isalpha result to initiate an if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, isalpha

Okay, so I have a for loop that checks through every letter of a string to make sure that the string is made entirely of alphabetical characters before moving on to the next stage of the program.

However, I am having trouble with my if statement that is supposed to run if the "isalpha" function comes back false.

```
string keyword = argv[1];
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(keyword); i++)
{
    char letter = keyword[i];
    if (isalpha(letter) = false)
    {
        printf("Only use alphabetical characters in your key\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

I am getting the error:

> error: expression is not assignable
>           if (isalpha(letter) = false)

How can I get an if statement that initiates due to a isalpha being false?

How is the following wrong?

```
if (isalpha(letter) = false)
```

Comment: It's `==`. Or just `!isalpha(letter)`.

Comment: We're not human debuggers, you should fix compiler problems yourself.

Comment: @BetaRunner It's not even debuggers, but error message parsers...

Comment: Indeed looks stupid, but in favor of the OP, if his compiler really shows the cited message, this is not entirely clear just showing the whole line...

Comment: @FelixPalmen - perfectly clear (to me)

Comment: @KevinDTimm it doesn't state what the "expression" is, that's not "assignable". I don't say this couldn't have been solved with just some "*google skills*", still, coming from another language where `=` compares things and seeing *this* error message talking about the whole line as an expression that is not assignable -- it's at least not immediately obvious.

Comment: Classic case where yoda programming might have helped, given the odd message OP got from his compiler.

Comment: The C tag. IMO the "recently" added boolean type was a wrong turn for C. It is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah, why don't we just program universal turing machines with tape?

Answer (score 3):

You made a typo: `if (isalpha(letter) = false)` is not a comparison, but an assignment.  You should instead write:

```
if (isalpha(letter) == false)
```

A more common way to write this is with the `!` operator:

```
if (!isalpha(letter))
```

Note however that `isalpha()` has undefined behavior for negative values different from `EOF`, and if the `char` type is signed, the value if `letter` can be negative. This problem is corrected with a cast:

```
if (!isalpha((unsigned char)letter))
```

Comment: Yes, but `isalpha` and cousins take `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane:  `isalpha()` and friends from `<ctype.h>` take an `int`, but are only defined for all values of type `unsigned char` and the special negative value `EOF`.  A negative `char` argument is promoted to `int` with the same value, and unless it happens to be the same as `EOF`, the behavior is undefined. If the `char` has the same value as `EOF`, the behavior is defined but potentially incorrect: `'ÿ'` has value `-1` for character set ISO-8859-1, will be treated as `EOF` which is commonly defined to the same value.  It is basically the same problem as `char c = getchar();`.

Comment: The value of the character must be passed as an `unsigned char` for it to be meaningful. `char` can be signed by default, but whenever character values are used in the C library, it is the value of the `unsigned char` that is considered: `strcmp()` compares the string bytes as converted to `unsigned char`, like `memcmp()` for which it is less questionable, `getchar()` returns the value of a byte from the stream as an `unsigned char`, `putchar()` converts its argument to an `unsigned char` and returns that... All functions from `<ctype.h>` need unsigned character values or the value `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

> How is the following wrong?

```
if (isalpha(letter) = false)
```

Well, it's an *assignment*! `=` is used to *assign a value*, and you can't assign a value to a function call (for hopefully obvious reasons)

To compare values, you use the `==` operator in C.

That said, checking for equality with `==` is not necessary at all when you already have *boolean* values. Just write:

```
if (!isalpha(letter))
```